# Shift frame inside UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, nib

My universal app uses NIBs for its settings screens. I'd like to use the same NIBs for both iPhone and iPad.

Thus on iPad, I use a UIPopoverController in the MainViewController and for settings, simply display the iPhone-sized NIBs, to show what is called the SettingsViewController. The popover is sized 320x460 points.

This causes a problem, because the iPhone version draws a number of things above the status bar programmatically, and for the iPad version this is not necessary. Current situation on iPad:

[image]

As you can see, there's a big empty space above the "Settings" title. Thus what I want, is to shift the view controller up about 20 points, **inside the popover**:

[image]

The popover is instantiated as follows in the MainViewController:

```
        settingsPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverNavigationController];
        settingsPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 460);
        settingsPopoverController.delegate = self;
        popoverNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

In the SettingsViewController, I set the frame as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 460);
}
```

And later in the SettingsViewController, I try to create an offset as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    // shift it up
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -20;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
}
```

This does not shift the content up a bit. How to go about?

*To clarify: I want to move down the "viewport" that the popover shows.*

Answer (score -1):

Try to:

```
myPopover.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Or:

```
myPopover.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight || UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

You can also try to put your code in `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.
If this answers did not help, try set `popoverLayoutMargins` (property) instead of `setFrame:` for example:

```
popover.popoverLayoutMargins=UIEdgeInsetsMake (
CGFloat 50, //top
CGFloat 50,//left
CGFloat 50,//bottom
CGFloat 50//right
);
```

Comment: UIPopoverController doesn't have the autoresizingMask property, not sure what you mean.

Moving the code to viewDidLayoutSubview doesn't have any effect.

Comment: In IB try to set sligment constraints' priority to min value.

Comment: Are you need to move popover view or popover arrow?

Comment: I add one more solution in my answer.

Comment: I need to move the content of the popover, not the popover itself. I've added an extra mockup.

Comment: Did you try - (void)setPopoverContentSize:(CGSize)size animated:(BOOL)animated method?

Comment: Try to increase height value from 460 to 480. May be your popover's content has top margin, because on this place should be navigation bar.